# Stata - How to get Indicator Variable Indicators (Yes/No) to Appear in esttab LaTeX Output

Tags: label, latex, regression, stata

Suppose I use this dataset:

```
sysuse nlsw88, clear
```

I want to run a regression and save it to a .tex file using esttab. The regression is this:

```
reg wage grade i.industry i.occupation, robust
```

Importantly, I want to indicate that I am using industry and occupation dummies, but I do not want any of the coefficients to appear in the table.

One way to do this is to hardcode industry and occupation indicators:

```
eststo clear
eststo: reg wage grade, robust
estadd local industry "No"
estadd local occupation "No"
eststo: reg wage grade i.industry i.occupation, robust
estadd local industry "Yes"
estadd local occupation "Yes"
esttab est* using "${path}/regress_wage.tex", r2 ar2 b(3) se label booktabs ///
    replace nodepvars nomtitles drop(*industry *occupation) ///
    scalars("industry Industry" "occupation Occupation")
```

But I would really like to not have to manually put these in. I found out about the indicate `option`, but I can't get it to work with `i.` variables. I have tried:

```
eststo clear
eststo: reg wage grade, robust
eststo: reg wage grade i.industry i.occupation, robust
esttab est* using "${path}/regress_wage.tex", r2 ar2 b(3) se label booktabs ///
    replace nodepvars nomtitles drop(*industry *occupation) ///
    indicate(Industry = *industry*)
```

I have also tried swapping the last line out for:

```
    indicate(Industry = _Iindustry*)
    indicate(Industry = industry*)  
    indicate(Industry = *industry)
```

But nothing works. What to do?

Also, is there a way to get the `Industry` and `Occupation` indicators to appear right below the constant as opposed to below the adjusted R-squared?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `coefl` option to see how coefficients are named, which will be useful for referring to them in the `indicate()`:

```
sysuse nlsw88, clear
reg wage grade i.industry i.occupation, robust coefl
esttab, indicate("Industry = *.industry" "Occupation = *.occupation")
esttab, indicate("Industry = *.industry" "Occupation = *.occupation", labels("In"))
```